# Problem with proof about sets: $( A\setminus B)^{C}=A^{C}\cup ( A\cap B )$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

When $A$, $B$ are sets, prove  that

> $\left ( A\setminus B \right )^{C}=A^{C}\cup \left ( A\cap B \right )$

I'm having difficulties trying to prove this because I don't understand what $C$ is. Can anyone let me know?

I'd also like some help in proving the identity:  Can anyone give me direction on this?

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Often a stylized $C$ (_e.g._ $A^\complement$) is used to indicate the complement of a set.  It's probably best not to use an ordinary $C$ because $A^C$ might mean the set of functions from a set $C$ into the set $A$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First: $^C$ means the "complement" of the set: e.g. $A^C$ means the elements of the universal set which are NOT IN $A$.

Assuming $A, B \subseteq X$ for some universal set $X$,

then the statement is asking for you to prove the equality:

$$\left ( A\setminus B \right )^{C}=A^{C}\cup \left ( A\cap B \right )$$

This can be done by whowing that each side of the equality is the subset of the other set, by "element chasing":

We want to prove that $$(A\setminus B)^C \subseteq A^C\cup (A \cap B)\tag{1}$$ 
and $$A^C \cup (A\cap B) \subseteq A\setminus B)^C\tag{2}$$

And we do this, for $(1)$, e.g., by element chasing:

$x \in (A\setminus B)^C \implies x \notin (A\setminus B) \implies ... \implies $ hence, $x \in A^C\cup(A\cap B)$

And for $(2)$:

$x \in A^C \cup(A\cap B) \implies x\notin A \lor x \in (A\cap B) \implies x \notin A \lor (x \in A \land x \in B)\implies...\implies $, hence, $x \in (A\setminus B)^C$